# Keep processes running in Linux after disconnected to terminals, a ctrl+D solution?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

For years I've been using `nohup` or `screen` to keep processes running after I disconnect to the terminal through SSH. So it quite shocked me when one of my friends, a green hand at Linux or CS, told me <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (or `exit`) could do the same thing, and probably in a more elegant way.

So here's how to do it: First run your process in the background just as usual (by adding `&` or using `bg`, whatever), then, when you want to disconnect from the terminal, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or `exit` to log out.

I know <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or `exit` are very common ways to log out. But after you log in again, you'll find the process you've just initiated running.... This may sound hard to believe and I said I was shocked. I tried the method in several different situations, including simple dead loop python scripts, it indeed worked.

I tried to search for some information about this but it seems everybody is talking about `nohup` or `screen`. Is the method I'm talking about a common knowledge? Is it just a specific feature for some systems or environments? If it is available generally then what's the meaning of `nohup`?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> maps to EOT in the ASCII table. In many (most?) cases this is mapped to EOF, which implies that there is no more data.

For terminals (for example `bash` running with a tty as `stdin`), calling `read()` when there is no user input will usually block, or return zero (no data to read). When the tty "*goes away*", `bash` will finally read an EOF, stating that there is categorically no more input - ever. You can present an EOF manually by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

It's worth noting that things like `bash` that use `readline` will not present the EOF unless the current line is empty. Try typing anything and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - nothing will happen.

When `bash` is executed with a script as input (e.g: running with a file as `stdin`), then once the last byte has been read, `read()` will return EOF. At this point the script is complete, and `bash` exits. This is the same behaviour as the terminal.

If you put a process in the background (end the command with `&`, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and `bg`), then you are returned to the shell. At this point killing the shell will have different effects on the process, depending on what it does.

- A process with a file as `stdin` will likely continue to execute, now inherited by init (PID 1).
- A process with a pipe from `bash` as `stdin` will also continue to execute... **Until** it tries to call `read()`. at this point, the `read()` will fail, and the application will either absorb the error and continue, or (more likely) quit with an error.

---

[`SIGHUP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) (aka Hang-Up) is a signal that is given to a process to inform it that the other end has 'hung up'. I appreciate that this may be an arcane concept... but in this usage, it informs the process that the SSH client has disconnected, or informs a child of `bash` that `bash` has quit, etc...

If a process does not explicitly handle `SIGHUP`, then the default action is to terminate it. Thus asking `bash` *not to* send a `SIGHUP` to one of it's children will effectively allow it to run after the shell has gone away.

---

If you want to leave a command running in the background without laying the groundwork first (look into [`tmux`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) as a better version of `screen`), then you'll need to specifically state "*I don't want this process attached to this shell any more*".

To achieve this, you can use `disown` ([ref here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), but you'll need to search/scroll), which will tidy things up for you, and leave the process running:

> disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]
>
> Without options, each jobspec is removed from the table of active jobs. If jobspec is not present, and neither -a nor -r is supplied, the shell's notion of the current job is used. If the -h option is given, each jobspec is not removed from the table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the shell receives a SIGHUP. If no jobspec is present, and neither the -a nor the -r option is supplied, the current job is used. If no jobspec is supplied, the -a option means to remove or mark all jobs; the -r option without a jobspec argument restricts operation to running jobs. The return value is 0 unless a jobspec does not specify a valid job.

Things will still probably go wrong if the process tries to `read()` from `stdin`, so if you explicitly want to disconnect a running process, then either make sure that `stdin` is pointing at `/dev/null` or similar, or use `tmux` ahead of time.

---

NOTE: writing to `stdout` or `stderr` will probably be as deadly as trying to read from `stdin` in these cases... SIGPIPE ahoy.

---

It's possible, with the aid of tools to redirect `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` of a running process, making it much safer to leave, by using debug system calls (you may have difficulty, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308661/1347519)). I'm struggling to remember the name of a C application I've used in the past, but a little rummaging has shown up [`dupx`](https://www.isi.edu/~yuri/dupx/) which may also help, or at least be interesting to look into.

Both operate by fundamentally doing the following within the target process:

```
fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
dup2(fd, stdin);
close(fd);

fd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
dup2(fd, stdout);
dup2(fd, stderr);
close(fd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can only use `nohup` or `screen` if you know prior to running your command that you'll need it to continue before you log off.

What happens when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is that the input buffer is sent to the running process. Now what happens next depends on what application you're currently in.

In most (all?) terminal emulators and terminals it'd simply log out you, ending the process. This means if you had a process running in the background, which wasn't `nohup`'ed or in a `screen` session, it *would* die along with your log out.

However it's possible that you're within some application, that using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> isn't actually ending it, but putting it into some background state.

Another thought is that your friend was thinking about <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> - this will pause the running process, which you can then 'disconnect' from the running terminal session using `bg` and `disown`. Once you've done this you can close your terminal. This is basically the same as using `nohup` before running the process.

You can't 'reattach' to a process like this, once it's been disowned however.